# Are Over-the-Air Updates possible with NB-IoT

Tags: over-the-air-updates

I'm trying make an IoT device which I want be a highly power saving one & want it to work in a remote static environment. So I plan to make a circuit with a "SARA" NB IoT module. Now I want to know if FOTA is possible with NB_IOT.

Comment: See https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/sara-n3-series - so yes, it appears if you use the SARA-N3 variant. (It does appear variant specific).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, explicitly so, albeit it will be relatively slow.

Carriers are actually recommending NB-IoT and Cat-M1 combo modules, and dynamically switching to M1 when FOTA is needed, although this will only make sense for some apps.